# Find span with specific class after input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask how to find a span element with a specific class.

The html is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox">
<span class="one">One</span>
<span class="two">Two</span>
```

I am trying like this, but it doesn'work:

```
 $(".checkbox").on('click',function() {

                $(this).closest('span').find('.one').hide();  
            });
```

Comment: Are there multiple elements with the one class? If not, why find it? Why not just hide class one

Comment: This doesn't work because `.closest()` traverses *upwards* (ancestors), not laterally (siblings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".checkBox").on('click',function() {
        $(this).siblings('span').each(function(){
           if($(this).hasClass('one'))
           $(this).hide()
        })                
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox">
<span class="one">One</span>
<span class="two">Two</span>
```

You can use siblings method for spans.

```
  $(".checkbox").on('click',function() {
        $(this).siblings('span').each(function(){
           if($(this).hasClass('one'))
           $(this).hide()
        })                
    });
```

Comment: Why add the additional `hasClass` method and conditional when the selector can be `span.one`?

Comment: if not check it will hide all span

Comment: No.... if the siblings selector is `span.one` it will only find elements that match that.  Doing the selector as just `span` is causing you to add in the additional conditional and method call which is logical bloat that is a bit of reinventing the wheel that the sibling selector can already do for you

Answer (score 2):

Two issues.

## 1) `class="checkBox"` != ".checkbox"

Classes are case sensative.  You need to fix that.

## 2) The spans are not ancestors of the checkbox

They are siblings.  `closest()` works by going up the DOM tree and looking for ancestors.  It does not look for siblings.  You can use `siblings()` to try to find the `span.one`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.siblings()` selector:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('span.one').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox">
<span class="one">One</span>
<span class="two">Two</span>
```

Note though that your `$(".checkbox")` is wrong as your input doesn't have that *class* but has that *type*

Answer (score 0):

`closest` moves up in the dom, so use `next`.

```js
$(".checkBox").on('click', function() {

  $(this).next('.one').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox">
<span class="one">One</span>
<span class="two">Two</span>
```